# changing collection name in ng-repeat in $compile phase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that makes things repeatable. For example, `<div repeat-this><p>hey</p></div>` will repeat  `<p>hey</p>` , say, 5 times.

In the `$compile` function of `repeat-this` I wrap all the contents in a

```
<div class="repeatable" ng-repeat="item in collection">contents go here<div>
```

so that AngularJS takes care of replicating elements, the scope, etc for me.

However, the name of this collection is declared with a directive `myCollectionName` and can change depending on where the directive is (there are some ng-includes that can include more `myCollectionName` but consumers of this name should only use the closest one in the hierarchy). I can get the name of the collection using a directive controller in a parent element but then it is only available in the postLink function of `repeat-this` and I can't modify the `item in collection` part to make it like `item in students` or `item in tickets`. What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: It would be good to see this as a plunk/fiddle so we can play around with it. But based on your description I would pass the name of the collection as an argument to the repeat-this directive so repeat-this="myCollectionName"

Comment: Not sure about the scenario, but if you can get the collection at post link, you an assign it to a scope variable `collection` and binding will pick it up.

Comment: yeah sorry for not providing a plunkr. it was hard to make a simplified example work. I passed it in as a parameter combining both of your ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing properties from scope within a directive you should never access the property directly.

For example (within a directive):

```
scope.myProperty = 'myval';
```

You should instead pass in the name of the property as a parameter to the directive:

```
<div myDirective="myProperty">
```

Inside your directive you can then use the passed in parameter to access the property:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
  var propertyAccessor = $parse(attrs.myDirective);

  propertyAccessor.assign(scope, 'myval');
}
```

Using $parse is important because it allows you to use nested properties for instance `myDirective="item.myProperty"`

Comment: Eduard, in the end - did you end up doing something like $parse(attrs.myDirective).assign(scope, 'item in ' + newCollection) ? Would you happen to remember what kind of resolution you had?